# Python3.5-How to delete (release GPU memory) a variable from inside a function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I defined a function in Python 3.5 called 'evaluate' and the code is shown below ('REC_Y', 'REC_U', 'REC_V' represent the 3 channels of a YCbCr image respectively):

```
import numpy as np


def evaluate(REC_Y, REC_U, REC_V):
    height = 832
    width = 480

    bufY = np.reshape(np.asarray(REC_Y), (height, width))

    bufU = np.reshape(np.asarray(REC_U), (int(height / 2), int(width / 2)))

    bufV = np.reshape(np.asarray(REC_V), (int(height / 2), int(width / 2)))

    return (np.stack((bufY, bufU, bufV), axis=2))
```

In order to release some GPU memory (since I already had a GPU MemoryError), I'd like to remove 'REC_Y','REC_U','REC_V' from memory after the last line of the code (after 'bufV = np.reshape(np.asarray(REC_V), (int(height / 2), int(width / 2)))'). I have tried 'del REC_Y', but it shown 'REC_Y' referenced before assignment. I have tried del global()["REC_Y"] but it shown that "REC_Y" is not defined as a global variable.

Could you please help me with this issue? How to delete 3 parameters of 'evaluate' function to release GPU memory?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**`Numpy` does not work** on GPU.

Only if you had CUPY or CUDA operations could you try to free some memory on the GPU -> `numpy` works on CPU.

Comment: Hi Timbus, Yes, I had CUDA operations and this code was also executed on GPU. But I am not sure how to delete parameters from inside a function free memory. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I helped you. The code that you provided cannot be executed on GPU, only if you use MinPy or CUPY. Please not that if you do have some GPU execution, this code will not execute on GPU but on CPU.

Comment: Thanks Timbus! Is there any way to delete parameters of a function in Python? Since I encountered some errors (listed in my question) when using 'del' command. Many thanks!

Comment: The only operation to work in this case is 'del'. If this does not work, then there is a problem with your code/you do something wrong at a point. If my answer helped you kindly upvote, others may find it useful.